# nginx location block matching order query

Tags: nginx

I have the following in my conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name a.mydomain.com;

    location /f/ {
        alias /var/www/sites/mydomain/photos/;
        expires 1y;
    }

    location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
        include php.conf;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 http://www.mydomain.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Where php.conf is

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  "include_path=.:/usr/share/pear:/var/www/sites/mydomain/conf";
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_index index.php;
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

What puzzles me, is that my final location ("location /") block, does exactly what I want it to.  Any request other than those starting with /f/ get redirect to the parent www domain.

Which is great, **it's what I want.**

**But,** the documentation states otherwise.  It says that the regex php block I have should match before (and take precedence) over the final "/" block?

Doesn't it?

"The order in which location directives are checked is as follows:

- Directives with the = prefix that match the query exactly (literal string). If found, searching stops.
- All remaining directives with conventional strings. If this match used the ^~ prefix, searching stops.
- Regular expressions, in the order they are defined in the configuration file.
- If #3 yielded a match, that result is used. Otherwise, the match from #2 is used."

Comment: Does a request for a php or html file also get redirected? Like `a.mydomain.com/myfile.php`?

Comment: Yes, that ends up at www.mydomain.com/myfile.php

Comment: Looks like you are correct (but I didn't confirm it). It's what you want! :) To find out what it's *really* doing, you can look at the source! Not sure if it's worth it, though.